# R data.table and knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I have an automated report that i produce using knitr.  i'm running across the oddest problem.  I wrote a function that sums the data by month for several locations.  when i run this function in R i get the following result (which is correct):

NAME MONTH      VOL

#### 1: TOTAL     1 13.00872

#### 2: TOTAL     2 11.62527

#### 3: TOTAL     3 12.71313

#### 4: TOTAL     4 12.67269

#### 5: TOTAL     5 15.05127

#### 6: TOTAL     6 14.61002

#### 7: TOTAL     7 15.43827

#### 8: TOTAL     8 15.22400

#### 9: TOTAL     9 14.91259

#### 10: TOTAL    10 15.83505

#### 11: TOTAL    11 14.97242

#### 12: TOTAL    12 16.34950

when i run this same function (no changes) through knitr to produce the report i get the following result:

#### NAME MONTH VOL

#### 1: TOTAL 1 14.00872

#### 2: TOTAL 2 13.62527

#### 3: TOTAL 3 15.71313

#### 4: TOTAL 4 16.11338

#### 5: TOTAL 5 17.61269

#### 6: TOTAL 6 18.46945

#### 7: TOTAL 7 20.18851

#### 8: TOTAL 8 21.04382

#### 9: TOTAL 9 21.72287

#### 10: TOTAL 10 23.54272

#### 11: TOTAL 11 23.72971

#### 12: TOTAL 12 26.03293

i also have another table where knitr just prints non-sense even though the table has actual values in it.

Here is my session info:

R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.3.3  xtable_1.7-4     shape_1.4.2      reshape2_1.4.1   rgdal_0.9-2      raster_2.2-12
[7] sp_1.0-17        png_0.1-7        data.table_1.9.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.8    evaluate_0.5.5  formatR_1.1     grid_3.1.2      knitr_1.9       lattice_0.20-29 memoise_0.2.1
[8] packrat_0.4.3   plyr_1.8.1      Rcpp_0.11.5     stringr_0.6.2   tools_3.1.2

Comment: This is really an R question and would be better answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r.  But you need to check that the same packages are loaded when you run knitr.  Try running the knit function inside a R session both before and after you run your function in the R session.

Comment: i will post there then.

Comment: An MWE as a full .rnw file would help

Comment: i posted in the R section of stacked exchange.